# What is the それ in それゆけ?

Tags: expressions

As I understand it, それゆけ is an interjection that might be translated "Go!" or "Go get 'em!"

While the second component is clearly 行け, what is the intended sense of それ here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

それ here is an interjection (感動詞). It's like 掛け声.

[デジタル大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%85%B6%E3%82%8C/#jn-131738) says:

> それ【其れ】
>   ➁［感］人に注意を促すときなどに発する語。そら。ほら。「其れ見なさい」「**其れ行け**」

The pronoun それ (for "that") is [それ]{LH}. The interjection それ is [それ]{HL}.

Comment: 「それいけ！」って聞くと「アンパンマン！」って思ってしまう。

Comment: Nice! What's the pitch accent for それゆけ as a whole?

Comment: @jogloran 「[それゆけ]{HLLL}！」って言いますね。